# как вынести данные из объекта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как вынести данные из объекта в отдельные переменные, чтобы при использовании каждый раз не писать object.name, object.text и т.д.?

```
  const { object } = this.props;
```

так не получается. undefined

```
  conxt {text} = object.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [деструктуризация объекта](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring#%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)

```js
const object = {
  name: 'name1',
  text: 'text1'
}

const { name, text } = object;

console.log(name, text)
```

Comment: Спасибо! получилось

Answer (score 1):

Если у тебя props undefined - то и object тоже будет undefined. Проверь к чему привязан this.

Comment: у меня не undefined. когда я просто вывожу object.text, то все ок. как только завожу переменую и записываю туда и вывожу ее, undefined

Comment: если вывожу просто object.text, то  сначала undefined, а потом само значение выводится. почему так

Comment: когда в переменную записываю и вывожу, просто undefined